# Application.Worksheetfunction.Max does not return the largest number in array

Tags: vba, excel, max, worksheet-function

I have an array filled with various double values, when I use the `Application.WorksheetFunction.max` Function I receive one value yet when I look at the individual values of the array I can find multiple values that are larger the value returned by `Application.WorksheetFunction.max`. Copied form the immediate window:

```
?Application.WorksheetFunction.max(dummyQuantileVector)
 21081,4351851852 
?dummyQuantileVector(73368)
 799470,509259259
```

What could be the cause of this?

Update: When I write the entire dummyQuantileVector array into a sheet and then use the use the max Function there I get the correct value.

Comment: You should provide sample data.  `21081,4351851852` and `799470,509259259` look like two different string values printed to the immediate window.

Comment: German Excel uses the , as the decimal separator.
When writing code I have to use . as the separator which can get a bit confusing in the immediate window.

Comment: IS `dummyQuantileVector` declared `dummyQuantileVector() As Double`?

Comment: Yes it is. I then use ReDim to get it into the size I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `WorksheetFunction.Max` will only work on the first 34465 elements of the array of a 1D array.  It will work properly on a 2D array.

[image]

### Custom Max Function

```
Function getMaxNumberFromArray(Data As Variant)
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim n As Double
    Dim flag As Boolean

    For Each v In Data
        If Not flag Then
            n = v
            flag = True
        ElseIf v > n Then
            n = v
        End If
    Next
    getMaxNumberFromArray = n
End Function
```

Comment: Probably more complicated. I filled 40000 cells with values form 1 to 40000 and `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max([A1:A40000].value)` returns 40000

Comment: Interesting, this seems to only be part of the problem though because there are values larger than the one returned by the max function with an index smaller than 34464:  
    `?dummyQuantileVector(13973)
     21153,287037037`

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help. It seems that this issue also applies to 1D arrays being used with the percentile function and most likely all other WorksheetFunctions that take arrays as inputs as well.

Comment: This issue comes up a lot in Excel.  Thanks for accepting my answer.